# Why doesn't this Mongo aggregation work?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I feel like I must be missing something obvious. Here is the aggregation, as one would post it in the shell:

```
db.documents.aggregate(
   { $project: { title: 1, "date.year": 1, decade:
   { $subtract: ['$date.year', { $mod: ['$date.year', 10]}]}
}})
```

This is supposed to take a list of documents, each with a date.year field, and add a decade field indicating which decade the document is in (1900, 1910, etc.) I'm planning on further transforming the data after I get that added.

The problem is that when I run the aggregation, I get:

```
{
    "errmsg" : "exception: $subtract resulted in a non-numeric type",
    "code" : 16413,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

If I change $subtract to $add, it works fine (but doesn't give me the right result, of course.) So what's going on with the subtraction? Why am I getting a non-numeric type when I subtract but a number when I add?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Worked fine when I tried it.  What do your docs look like?

Comment: Hi Johnny. Here's an abridged version:

`"title": "Something or other."
        "date" : {
                "year" : 1969,
                "month" : 12,
                "day" : 10,
                "full" : ISODate("1970-01-10T07:00:00Z")
        }`

I use the different date fields because not all the documents I'm working with (the physical documents I'm storing in the database) have full dates attached.

Comment: I know the full date doesn't match up with the date parts (year, month). That's something I'll fix next.

Comment: That one works fine too.  Do you perhaps have some docs where `date.year` isn't a number?

Comment: Johnny,

You got it! There are a few documents where date isn't set. That must be what's causing the problem!

Comment: I should add, I just discovered those documents now. They're not supposed to be there and I'll be talking to the people who set up the very large data set about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a [bug in the aggregation framework](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7932) - it's not handling subtraction correctly when the fields you are operating for are not set in the documents going through the pipeline.

It's been fixed in 2.3.2 (I can't reproduce this - it projects "null" when "date" is not set) but one way you can work around this limitation is by adding a $match condition to your pipeline, i.e. prefix {$project} with:

`{$match: {"date.year":{$exists:true}}}`

Comment: Thank you, Asya! I think you and Johnny nailed it. I've been banging my head against the wall for hours trying to figure it out.

Comment: Yep, just tried it with the $match condition set. That does the job. Fantastic! Thanks again!